# M4A audio stops early on android 5.0 on nexus 5

Tags: android, media-player, nexus-5

I'm writing an android audio player and on my nexus 5 running android 5.0 the MedaPlayer stops playing audio tracks around 2 to 5 seconds early. It's not predictable. It can change on the same track. Is there anyone else experiencing this, that found a workaround. I know this is not just my app that's having this issue on this device, because I tested it in Vanilla Music Player and it did the same thing. I've seen a few other people post on things sort of similar, but in most cases I see it has to do with steaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this answser:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27827402/1415199
This is a bug in Android.

> Ok it looks like the issue is Android 5.0.1's experimental MediaPlayer
>   called NuPlayer. NuPlayer is being enabled by default on all Android
>   5.0.1 devices and is only disabled through Developer Options. I've filed a bug against Android here:
>   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=94069&thanks=94069&ts=1420659450

The link above contains a suggested workaround